# Sitecore 10 Solr Indexing only on processing server

Tags: solr, processing

Our Sitecore CM has a huge amount of content data and whenever running the index from the control panel it's become a huge load on our Sitecore instance and took a couple of hours.

So, we want to shift the master and web index from the Sitecore CM server to the processing server.

Please guide me is it possible whenever we trigger indexing for master/web then it should run over the processing server instead of the CM server so that the IIS Sitecore CM website can be free from a huge load of indexing?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your CM, you should see its role is set to "ContentManagement,Indexing". The Indexing role is the one that's handling the processing. You can read more about this configuration in the Sitecore docs: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/enable-the-indexing-sub-role.html

I'm not sure if there's an additional step needed to trigger this indexing-only server, there might be. I'd suggest pinging Sitecore support if you don't get a better answer here.